# Add a custom line to a $String | Select | format-table output request

Tags: powershell

I am trying to add another line to the following table formatted menu:

```
$Manager = get-aduser (get-aduser $Aduser.SamAccountName -properties * | Select -ExpandProperty Manager) -properties *
$Team = get-aduser $manager.SamAccountName -properties directreports |  Select-Object -ExpandProperty directreports | Get-ADUser -Properties Name,mail | Select-Object Name,mail
$Team | Select @{Name="Teammember";Expression={$global:i++;$global:i}},name,mail -OutVariable menu | format-table -AutoSize

$r = Read-Host "Select which team member to use via number"
$replacement = $menu | where {$_.teammember -eq $r}
```

Which nicely produces a numbered menu for the operator to select from.

I would like to add a custom line so that at the end of the table, there is always the option to select "Custom". How is it possible to add a line to a pre-determined sized table? Any help appreciated!

Comment: Is the goal to add 'Custom' in the Teammember column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your code creates `$menu` as an `ArrayList`, you can use the `Add(System.Object value)` method to append to the collection. One option is to add your desired string value to a common property on a new object. Here `'Custom'` can be changed to any string.

```
[void]$menu.Add([pscustomobject]@{'Teammember' = 'Custom'})
```

A second option is to just add a string value to the collection. However, this will reduce flexibility later for menu selection.

```
[void]$menu.Add("Custom Selection")
```

Since `Add()` produces an `int` output (the index that contains the addition), we use the `[void]` cast for suppression.

`$menu` is ultimately a collection of objects that contain `Teammember`, `Name`, and `mail` properties. You can just append to that list with another object with any number of those properties set. You can add new properties to the new object, but you will have display issues with the table view.

As an aside, only use the `Format-*` commands for displaying output. It is not best practice to store `Format-*` output into variables that are expected to have future property changes or object additions. Your new code could be something like the following:

```
$Manager = Get-ADUser (Get-ADUser $Aduser.SamAccountName -properties Manager | Select -ExpandProperty Manager)
$Team = Get-ADUser $Manager.SamAccountName -Properties DirectReports |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty DirectReports |
        Get-ADUser -Properties Name,mail | Select-Object Name,mail
$null = $Team | Select-Object @{Name="Teammember";Expression={$global:i++;$global:i}},Name,Mail -OutVariable menu
[void]$menu.Add([pscustomobject]@{'Teammember' = 'Custom'})

# If you want to output Menu as a table
$menu | Format-Table -AutoSize

$r = Read-Host "Select which team member to use via number"
$replacement = $menu | where {$_.teammember -eq $r}
```

Comment: Thanks @AdminOfThings! That worked great! And cheers for the best-practice tip.

I modified one thing to complete it: 

``[void]$menu.Add([pscustomobject]@{teammember="X";Name="Custom"})``